# Group authors in title with revtex4-2

Tags: titles, revtex, collaboration

I'm using RevTex4-2 for an article. I want to group the first three authors together and put the last author in the second column. With the `\collaboration` command, I can do it. However, would it be possible to display the affiliations of the first three authors first, then the name and surname of the last author and his/her affiliation?

```
\documentclass[prx,noshowpacs,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{(}{\medskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{)}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \title{Title}
    
    \author{Author1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    
    \author{Author2}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    
    \author{Author3}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 3}
    
    \collaboration{}
    \author{Author4}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 4}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 5}
    
    \maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in this answer is a rather messy hack with undoubtedly many side effects. The best approach would probably be to leave the default behavior as it is.

However, if you are still interested in doing this, the following is an approach to call `\maketitle` twice, first for the first author block (with affiliations directly below) and then again for the remaining author(s).

Revtex4-2 clears all information after `\maketitle` (including the definition of `\maketitle` itself), so we need to preserve that in temporary commands. Also, atypically, the abstract is printed as part of `\maketitle` so this needs to be suppressed the first time and re-enabled the second time. The spacing needs to be adjusted and of course the title should not be printed the second time.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[prx,noshowpacs,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{(}{\medskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{)}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \title{Title}

    \begin{abstract}
    This is the abstract
    \end{abstract}
    
    \author{Author1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    
    \author{Author2}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    
    \author{Author3}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 1}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 2}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 3}

    \makeatletter
    % store affiliation, author macro definitions
    % before being cleared by first \maketitle
    \let\tmpaffiliation\affiliation
    \let\tmpauthor\author
    % store abstract macro definition before temporary clearing it
    % to prevent abstract being printed after first author block
    \let\tmpabstract\frontmatter@abstract@produce
    \let\frontmatter@abstract@produce\relax
    % prevent vertical space being added after first author block
    \let\frontmatter@finalspace\relax
    % print title and first author block
    \maketitle
    
    % restore definition of vertical space at end of author block
    \def\frontmatter@finalspace{\addvspace{18\p@}}
    % restore definitions of \maketitle, affiliation, author, abstract
    \let\maketitle\frontmatter@maketitle
    \let\affiliation\tmpaffiliation
    \let\author\tmpauthor
    \let\frontmatter@abstract@produce\tmpabstract
    % prevent printing title a second time
    \let\frontmatter@title@produce\relax
    \makeatother
    \author{Author4}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 4}
    \affiliation{Affiliation 5}
    % print second author block
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

One side effect that I didn't bother to fix is a multiply-defined `FirstPage` label somewhere in `\titleblock@produce`. You can probably remove that with `xpatch` but there is surely a lot of other bookkeeping that is affected by calling `\maketitle` twice - so check carefully.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted.